# Unable to import typescript module from global node_modules folder

Tags: typescript, node-modules

I have a library folder in global node modules
library/src/index.ts file inside that library

```
//inside index.ts
export * from './components/button.component
```

Now I want to import this in my angular-cli app
my angular-cli app has tsconfig.ts has `"moduleResoulution": "node"`

how can i import this as I am getting error 'cannot find moudule'
on doing

```
import * from 'library';
```

//Update

ok so I got `import { ButtonComponent } from 'library/src/index` working
but I want to get rid of src/index part

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare a namespace like so `import * as Library from 'library'`. This will allow you to use Library.ButtonComponent